# SuperUser shows far too many badges (I wish!)

Tags: bug, status-completed

My [SuperUser Account](https://superuser.com/users/2523/evilchookie) is now showing that I have 30 badges, but I only have 7 or so. I've tried logging in and out .. not helping.

While I don't mind having 30 badges listed .. are there even 30 bronze badges? And can I get 30 badges for finding such a odd thing?

**Edit** Let me show some pichars.. and yes, my profile shows correctly, but answers and login bar do not display correctly. Is it just for me, or do other people see 30 badges when they look at my answers?

[image: The Login Bar at SuperUser]
[image: Display of my User Info on a question]

Answer (score 3):

it'll fix itself when you get another badge.

Answer (score 0):

I only see 7 badges.  Maybe this is related to the [madness from this morning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10392/how-did-i-get-a-peer-pressure-badge-w-o-3-vote).

Comment: Click through to one of his questions, where you will find that it does say that he has 30 bronze badges.

Answer (score 0):

@Jonathan and Pesto,
I think he refers to the 30 Bronze in his `SU Flair`,

```
<span title=\"30 bronze badges\">
```

Check his account on one of the other sites to see his SU-flair.

---

To answer you recent question, I can see the 30 Bronze in your flair in,

- questions you have asked
- accounts area

  - have also pasted the text from your flair above